# Weird graphical effect on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I' developing a small android maze game and I'm experiencing a strange effect which I can only describe via screenshot: http://www.virtualalbum.eu/fu/39/cepp1523110123182951.jpg

At first I thought I needed to set up antialiasing but the advices I followed to enable it changed nothing, and the effect appears to be a little too evident to be that anyway.

The labyrinth is composed with rectangular-based pieces for the walls and small square-based pillars between walls and on edges, plus a big square as the floor.

There are 4 lights, I don't know if that matters

I've been thinking about removing the small pillar faces adjacent to walls as you shouldn't see them anyway, but that would mean writing a lot of code and still wouldn't fix the zigzag with the floor.

Thanks a lot,
J

EDIT: After some more testing I'm starting to think it may be a z-fighting issue, does anyone has any idea on how to increase the depth buffer precision on android?

Comment: What's your `glFrustrum()`/`gluPerspective()` call look like?  If the near-to-far range is too large you'll end up wasting most of your Z-buffer resolution.

Comment: My glFrustum() call looks like this:         float size = .01f * (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(45.0) / 2); 
        gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / ratio, size / ratio, 0.01f, 100.0f); I have no gluPerspective() call. You're right 100 far plane is overkill, considering the current scene isn't bigger than 10, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, setting`gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);` the zigzag on the floor disappeared (as it's the first thing I draw), I was still having issues with the walls but for that I wrote some extra code (it wasn't that much after all) and I'm also saving some triangle.